# Плавный скрол background'а

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Здравствуйте, есть такой вопрос. Шарясь по сайтам, нашел такую "фишку" невзрачную. Как плавный скролл заднего фона, например как на сайте [WoW](http://worldofwarplanes.ru/).
Вопрос, как её сделать и как она называется?

Comment: ...Параллакс...Открыв консоль вы могли бы сами это посмотреть.

Comment: Этот эффект называется "параллакс". Реализацию на чистом CSS можно посмотреть, например, здесь: http://habrahabr.ru/post/235531/